# How to run index.php file in amazon EC2?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been newly introduced to AMAZON EC2 Server. Recently I created a micro instance EC2 Ubuntu and installed Apache, PHP & MySql.
I have some `PHP` files including an index.php. I have uploaded my files to  **/var/www/html** directory. Now when i open my Public DNS in browser it shows nothing. The same thing is working in my localhost setup.
Is there something enabling mod rewrite in EC2 Ubuntu instance ?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does "nothing" mean it is returning a 500 or 404 or what? does it work locally to the server? (`curl http://localhost:80/pagename`). is the security group set up correctly?

Comment: What i mean to say is that when you open your DNS in browser it opens index.html file stored in  /var/www/html directory as default.
But here in my EC2 i have deleted index.html and uploaded my index.php as i need to run PHP code. Other files are successfully opening. I have searched and came across that this can be possible when you  instruct Apache to treat .html files as PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable inbound and outbound rules for port 80 (http) in your security group(s) that is assigned for the instance. By default the only inbound rule is ssh (port 22) and all outbound rules are enabled. So you might only need to change the inbound rule.